# RadTreeView get the next node

Tags: c#, telerik, radtreeview

I have a RadTreeView and I am trying to get the next node of the Selected node. I am using the `node.next` property but I am getting the following error:

> In order to use Prev/Next you need to add the node to a valid node hierarchy bound to a RadTreeView.

Any Help pls ?

```
RadTreeNode node = new RadTreeNode();
RadTreeNode nodeNext = new RadTreeNode();
node = RadTreeView1.SelectedNode ;
nodeNext = node.Next;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RadTreeNode _NextNode=null;

_NextNode=RadTreeView1.SelectedNode.Next;
```

regards (tested and working)